# Callback before DOM modification on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to build a chrome extension which can strip of img tags in a web page. How can I handle the img tags that are added dynamically to the webpage using javascript.

I didn't find something that would help me solve the problem but learnt about two things. 
1. document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', nodeInsertedCallback);

This will give me a callback but by then the dom has been modified and img tags have been added to the page.

1. MutationObservers : This also looks like a callback post the change in the dom element.

Is there a way to get a callback before the actual change to the dom ? I can control whether that change is permitted or not ?

I'm looking for a solution that would work for most websites.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If it is to let users browser without images, then this shouldn't be a problem. You can inject CSS through the extension which would then hide (`img{ display: none!important;}`) all images until you deleted them via `DOMNodeInserted` callback.

Comment: Thanks @ArtjomB.Thats interesting to know. But I don't want to download these images in the first place. Can I run a js function before any of my dom is modified ?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. There are some *native* dom functions that you can override, but when the DOM is updated via `element.innerHTML="<img>…"` you're at a loss.